# Showing $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-x)^n = 0$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: limits

I believe this can probably be shown by applying the binomial theorem, but I am wondering if there is another (hopefully simpler) way

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Can you show this with the binomial theorem? If so, why not include that so that we can find a "simpler" method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The prospect of using the binomial theorem was mentioned in the OP.  Here, we present an approach that relies on the Bernoulli's Inequality, which is more elementary than the binomial theorem.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

Note that for any $0<x<1$,

$$0<(1-x)^n<\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}\tag1$$

Using Berenoulli's inequality on the right-hand side of $(1)$ reveals

$$0<(1-x)^n<\frac{1}{1+nx}\tag2$$

Applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-x)^n=0$$

for $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: I was not aware of (1). Is induction the best way to show it? (i.e. for $n=1$ it is true because $-x^2<0$. If we assume true for $n$, then $(1-x)^{n+1} < \frac{1}{(1+x)^n} (1-x) < \frac{1}{(1+x)^n} \frac{1}{1+x}$ where first inequality follows from assuming true for $n$, and second follows from $n=1$ case (implicitly using fact that $1-x>0$)

Comment: Note that $(1-x)(1+x)=1-x^2\le 1$ for all real $x$.  And so for $0<x<1$, $0<1-x<\frac1{1+x}$.  Consequently, we have $0<(1-x)^n<\frac1{(1+x)^n}$

Comment: thanks for clarifying

Comment: You're certainly welcome.  It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=1-x$. Then $0 < y < 1$ and so $y^n \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew I was missing something clever

Comment: And how does one show that $y^n\to0$ for $y\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the ratio test for sequences.

$$\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{(1-x)^n}=1-x<1$$ thus $(1-x)^n \to 0$

Or you can use  geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-x)^n =\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}< \infty$$

If $\sum_{n}a_n$ converges then we know that $a_n \to 0$ so $(1-x)^n \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $0<1-x<1$.  Thus we just need to show that $a^n$ goes to zero as n goes to $\infty$.  If you don’t know how to show this you can use the fact that there are rational numbers $q$ and $r$ such that $q < a < r$ and then use the Squeeze Theorem.  It’s easy to show that for a rational number in $(0, 1)$, $r^n$ goes to zero in the limit.